# Is it possible to apply FAPI #states to profile2 fields on the user registration form?

Tags: forms, users

I have a profile embedded into the user registration form and am trying to add a conditional to one of the fields in order to show/hide related fields.

The fields are all part of the same fieldgroup in the following layout:

```
username
email

profile (fieldset)
 - About you (fieldset)
  - fields

submit button
```

I think the issue is how to actually target the fields and apply `#states` to them.  Any ideas? I tried digging through Devel Themer, but couldn't get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter a form, you need to [create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/1074360) and implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) (or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)) in it. In your hook_form_alter implementation you will have the $form array available. Look up the element you're interested in and add a #states property to it.

The above is just theory; I have not tried it specifically with the profile2 form and a #states property, but I assume that it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's odd, I've been trying to do exactly what you said, but can't seem to get to the actual field element that I need.  I'm thinking some things have changed considerably under the hood.

Last night I used dsm($form) in my module (based on http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) for both user_register_form and user_profile_form and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Did you try to [increase the module weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) of your custom module, to make sure it runs after profile2 adds its field to the form?

Comment: Funny you ask, actually I did end up figuring that out today.  Took a bit of digging since the method is different in D7 to set module weights.